# How to add Data Validation in a Cell using VBScript

Tags: excel, validation, vbscript

I am trying to add Data Validation in an Excel Cell using VBScript but I can't figure the correct syntax. I can do it in VBA, it is not a problem, but I need to do it in VBScript.
I just need to Add Validation with Values: "Yes", "No" into the cell.

Relevant code:

```
Dim xlValidateList

xlValidateList = 3

For s = 2 to sheetCount
  For r = 2 to sourceTotalRows
    xlBookSource.Sheets(s).Cells(r,23).Validation.Add xlValidateList, "Yes,No"
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the smart quotes are a typo, you have the formula as the wrong argument:

```
xlBookSource.Sheets(s).Cells(r,23).Validation.Add xlValidateList, , , "Yes,No"
```

Comment: Super. Thank you very much Rory :) I confirm that this solves the problem. I tend to forget that VBScript requires those comma's.